# What are the fewest jquery-ui css files I need to reference to use the Tabs widget?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui

I'm confused about just which jquery css files I need to reference in my asp.net site. Should I use just "jquery.ui..css" (such as "jquery.ui.tabs.css") if only uisng one jQuery-UI widget (as opposed to using "jquery.ui.all.css")?

Do I need to reference "jquery-ui.css" as a prerequisite for using the other jquery.ui.*.css files?

I see that jquery.ui.all.css imports base and theme, and jquery-ui.css seems to include everything (Includes: jquery.ui.core.css, jquery.ui.accordion.css, jquery.ui.autocomplete.css, jquery.ui.button.css, jquery.ui.datepicker.css, jquery.ui.dialog.css, jquery.ui.progressbar.css, jquery.ui.resizable.css, jquery.ui.selectable.css, jquery.ui.slider.css, jquery.ui.tabs.css, jquery.ui.theme.css)

Is including css support for all these widgets I'm not going to use wasteful or is the added "weight" negligible?

Of course, to make it as skinny as possible, I'll use the minified versions.

Comment: If you are using tabs and nothing else then `jquery.ui.tabs.css` should suffice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your css ui package and download here..http://jqueryui.com/download/